# email hosting de dominio registrado en otra compañia

Tags: email, dns, hosting

Que tal, tengo este problema, tengo un dominio registrado en godaddy y quiero hostear el servicio de email en bluehost, que es lo que tengo que hacer para que funciona, he visto sobre modificar los MX records o agregar o modificar CNAMES pero ya lo he hecho y no funciona.

Saludos

Comment: Hola Daniel, bienvenido a Stackoverflow en Español. Antes que nada te invito a visites el [tour] para que conozcas un poco de qué va esta comunidad de programadores. Tengo la impresión que tu pregunta está fuera del alcance del sitio, pero hay que esperar otras opiniones. A continuación te pido que edites tu pregunta siguiendo esta guía: [mcve]. Por último, te recomiendo esperar a que se propaguen las actualizaciones.

Comment: Voto para cerrar esta pregunta como tema no relacionado porque no parece una pregunta relacionada con el alcance del sitio.